# Ger Wikipedia Page Content with Introduction Using API

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to get Page Content with Abstract using API, as following:

```
https://ar.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&titles=pageTitle&redirects&prop=pageprops|categories|extracts&exintro=|revisions&rvprop=size|user|content&cllimit=500
```

extracts&exintro=: the Introcution Section
revisions: the Content
However this query doesn't return the Introduction section and raised the following error: 
`Unrecognized parameter: rvprop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how to add `prop=extracts&exintro=` to your existing query. You can't just add `&exintro=` in the middle of the existing `prop=` values, it has to be separate:

```
https://ar.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&titles=pageTitle&redirects&prop=pageprops|categories|extracts|revisions&exintro=&rvprop=size|user|content&cllimit=500
```